# Possibility of Cell level calculation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, formula, powerbi-desktop, business-objects

I am migrating SAP BO Webi reports to Power BI.

In SAP BO Webi report, visuals are in tabular format but one strange thing I have observed over here is that in a particular column the formula for every row is different. Further, in SAP BO the developers are able to edit the formula in every cell of the column. Now I need to replicate the same tabular visual in Power BI, but in Power BI we usually drag and drop rows and columns so how can we have separate formulas for separate rows in a column?

Kindly let me know if anyone have faced a similar challenge and found a solution for the same.

Thanks

I am not getting any solution for the same. So could not try as of now.